# How to use indexOf method on strings to extract string multiple times?

Tags: java, indexof

I have 3 different strings and from each one of those I'm trying to extract specific string using `indexOf` and `substring`. However, I don't want to repeat `indexOf` so may times in the code. Is there a way I could reuse a code to extract string I want from given larger strings? Any help will be great, thank you so much!

```
String message1 = content1.substring(content1.indexOf(" \\\"message\\\": \\") + 1, content1.indexOf("\\\" }")).substring(15);
String message2 = content2.substring(content2.indexOf(" \\\"message\\\": \\") + 1, content2.indexOf("\\\" }")).substring(15);
String message3 = content3.substring(content3.indexOf(" \\\"message\\\": \\") + 1, content3.indexOf("\\\" }")).substring(15);
```

Comment: Pass an `int` to `indexOf` as the second parameter. That `int` is the **starting** index for the search.

Comment: Shouldn't you be using a JSON parser instead?

Comment: You could add `16` instead of `1` to the starting index to avoid calling `substring` twice.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to write a method, which does exactly the same, try:

```
public static String extractMessage(String content){
  return content.substring(content.indexOf(" \\\"message\\\": \\") + 1, content.indexOf("\\\" }")).substring(15);
}
```

and then call it like this:

```
String message1 = extractMessage(content1);
String message2 = extractMessage(content2);
String message3 = extractMessage(content3);
```